# Joomla 2.5 Display Virtuemart category as a menu

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, virtuemart

I am using joomla 2.5 with virtuemart and i need a virtuemart product category as a main menu in joomla like a shopping cart website.

For example : main category as a main menu and sub category as a sub menu in main menu

Comment: Create a module to achieve your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this method in my one of the project.. Two ways is there..

1.You can use this module http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-categories/9902

2.Or you should link the Virtuemart category in main menu items, then you can call the main menu in menu module..

Thanks..

Comment: The 2nd way i prefer but how i call main menu in menu module?

Comment: It's little time taking method., because you want to create a menu for all virtuemart categories in main menu. And you can link the menu's to virtuemart category..
If you have any doubts refer this link please "http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/joomla-25/link-to-virtuemart-store-front"

Answer (score -1):

first of all, login in admin with username and password.

then go to menus - menus manager - create new.
in create new form - select Menu Item Type is VirtueMart Categories Layout.